# onclick delete will always delete the last row of the table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, onclick

I have this inside a while loop. Everytime I confirm the onclick delete of any table row it always deletes the last row.

```
echo '<td><a href="#openModal'.$id.'" data-toggle="modalDialog" data-target="#openModal"><img src=img/view.png width=20px height=20px id="view"></a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="deleteShit()"><img src="img/delete.png" width=20px height=20px name="delete"></a></td></tr>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteShit()
{
    if (confirm('Delete?'))
        window.location='delete.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>'
}
```

this is the delete.php page

```
$id=$_GET['id'];

$query = "UPDATE `main` SET status=0 where id = $id";
$sql = $db->prepare($query);
if ($sql->execute()) {
    echo "<script>
            window.alert('Item deleted!')
            window.location='view.php';
        </script>";
}
```

Comment: can you please print $query variable?? share here.

Comment: @SamratKhan what do you mean? im confused

Comment: @NeelIon i dont know how to use ajax that much thats why im not using it

Comment: does php printing the correct id for your window.location link?

Comment: check your source code, whether php printing correct id or not

Comment: that is the problem, it print the id of the last row, which means it deletes the data of last row.Always

Comment: post your php script which is fetching id

Comment: i think that is what i'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write your javascript function outer the while, with an arg :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteShit(id)
{
    if (confirm('Delete '+id+'?')) {
        window.location = 'delete.php?id='+id;
    }
}
</script>
```

And call the function with the arg :

```
echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="deleteShit(\''.$id.'\')"><img src="img/delete.png" width=20px height=20px name="delete"></a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: it still deletes the last row

Comment: please send your complete while() {  }

Comment: if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `main` WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY  `id` desc LIMIT $page1,5");
        $sql->execute();

        while($row = $sql->fetch()){

         $id = $row['id'];
         $company = $row['company_name'];
         $domain = $row['domain_name'];
         $industry = $row['industry_type'];

Comment: echo '<tr><td>'.$id.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$company.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$domain.'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$industry.'</td>';
         echo '<td><a href="#openModal'.$id.'" data-toggle="modalDialog" data-target="#openModal"><img src=img/view.png width=20px height=20px id="view"></a></td>';
         echo '<td><a href="#" onclick="deleteShit('.$id.')"><img src="img/delete.png" width=20px height=20px name="delete"></a></td></tr>';
         ?>
         
        </div>
         <?php }
         ?>

Comment: ok, this is correct (just you have a close div, why?). So, the id displayed in the confirm dialog 'Delte'+id is the right id you want to delete?

Comment: You can too add directly the confirm in the <a> : echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id='.$id.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Delete '.$id.'?\');"><img src="img/delete.png" width=20px height=20px name="delete"></a></td></tr>';

Comment: ohmy after one day it finally worked! Thanks alot :">